# SystemUi crash in recents

Tags: android

who can help me?I get in only Horizontal app 
[code]java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity.updateBlurBackgroundImageView(RecentsActivity.java)
    at com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity.onStart(RecentsActivity.java:554)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6334)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
    ... 11 more

[/code]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_0Jcz_4I06tOXRkbGcwb2w4MUE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: post your source code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_0Jcz_4I06tOXRkbGcwb2w4MUE/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

I think your view must be null.

If you want to call `setVisibility()` method of a view object which is not initialized, at that time this error occurs.

Please check, you must be forgotten to use `findViewById()`.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_0Jcz_4I06tOXRkbGcwb2w4MUE/view?usp=drivesdk